# How to call a custom cordova plugin from cordova app?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I am very new in cordova. I am trying to create a cordova plugin and trying to use it in another cordova app for android. I created the cordova plugin with help of plugman and  command prompt. Then I created a cordova app in visual studio 2015. I added the plugin in cordova app. When I am trying to access the plugin method from the app, its not working.
I am using following line to call the cordova plugin's method.

```
 cordova.exec(callback, error, "DemoPlugin", "getNextAppointment", [22]);
```

When the line exuctes I get following error:[image]

How I can fix this error, and we call the plugin method in right way in cordova app for android.

Comment: Have you tried window.plugins.DemoPlugin ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Ripple for your app. But Ripple doesn't support simulation of Cordova APIs or native device capabilities (plugins). Please refer to the first caution section of [Run your Apache Cordova app on the Apache Ripple simulator](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-ripple-simulator/).

If you want to test your plugin, please use an Emulator or actual device instead.